# conversation gets destroyed when invalidating a session

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, invalidation, httpsession, conversation-scope

I have a **SessionManager** which implements **HttpSessionListener**. In the **SessionManager**, I have a static hashtable of all active sessions. I am trying to create a function for forcing the invalidation of sessions. It looks something like :

```
HttpSession session = sessionRegistry.get(key);
session.invalidate();
```

That absolutely does what I want it to do, which is to destroy the targeted session. However, it seems to have a side effect on my **@ConversationScoped** managed bean.

In my **ConversationBean**, I have a property which holds some value. I just noticed that after invalidating a session from the **sessionRegistry**, the value stored on the ConversationBean gets destroyed.

- I was invalidating a different session (one from the **sessionRegistry** and not the current session)
- I printed the value from **ConversationBean** before and after invalidating the session and it is still there. It only gets destroyed once I leave the **@ViewScoped** page displaying the list of active sessions . (Caught it using **@PreDestroy**)
- Also, on the **@PreDestroy** annotated method of the **@ViewScoped** bean, I tried printing the Conversation Id and it is already nullified. And yes, the hash code for the **ConversationBean** is also different which means it a different instance from the one I had before invoking **session.invalidate**.

**---- EDIT ------**

This example demonstrates what I am trying to achieve :

Let's say I have an application scoped hashtable, **sessionRegistry**, with these values:

```
Key | Value
---------------------
1   | HttpSession1 
2   | HttpSession2 
3   | HttpSession3
```

I log in as an administrator. Now I believe I have a different session, let's say HttpSession4. I want to try to kick some session from the application scoped hashtable and I do it like this:

```
HttpSession session = sessionRegistry.get(1);
session.invalidate();
```

I destroyed **HttpSession1** while I was logged in on **HttpSession4**. In my understanding, the conversation of HttpSession1 should be destroyed with it and not the current conversation, which should be associated with HttpSession4.

My question is, is this really a normal behavior of **@ConversationScoped** managed beans? It seemed to be associating itself on the session I was invalidating.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html):

> When the HTTP servlet session is invalidated, all long-running conversation contexts created during the current session are destroyed, after the servlet service() method completes.

Comment: Conversations are stored in the Session, hence when the Session is invalidated so is the conversation

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. I edited my question and provided an example of what I want to achieve. If you have time to spare, please take a look at it. Again, thanks. I would also really love to know what @BalusC would say.

Comment: Why not create another question ?